# scala coursera functional programing assignment FunSets

Tags: scala, functional-programming, purely-functional

I have undergoing the functional programming course by martin odersky in scala on coursera. 

However, I am unable to understand the solutions to the 2nd Assignment Funsets.scala.

```
type Set = Int => Boolean

  /**
   * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
   */
  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

  /**
   * Returns the union of the two given sets,
   * the sets of all elements that are in either `s` or `t`.
   */
  def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
```

**Question** In the above **function what is e** ? Where does it come from ? I know that the union function combines the two sets, but here what I understood from the method definition is that it takes 2 sets as input and returns the resulting union set, so where does **e** come from ?

```
  /**
   * Returns the intersection of the two given sets,
   * the set of all elements that are both in `s` or `t`.
   */
  def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) && t(e)
```

The same question would be applicable for intersect function. 
Please can anybody explain me the operation of the above two functions i.e these two statements

`(e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)` and `(e: Int) => s(e) && t(e)`

Comment: `Set` **is** a function! So, in `intersect` you **return** a function. It is a function that returns a function. Might sound scary at first but it's very powerful. Same as you pass a "normal" parameter, you can pass a function (`Set` here). Like you're saying "If I had an *e* of type `Int` then the `intersect` would return..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is called a *parameter*. A parameter gets bound to an *argument* when the function is applied to an argument.

For example, in the function

```
val f: Int ⇒ Int = i ⇒ i + 1
```

`i` is a parameter. If if apply the function referenced by `f` to an argument, say, `2`, then inside the function, `i` is bound to the value of the argument, i.e. inside the function, dereferencing `i` evaluates to `2`. Thus, applying the function referenced by `f` will evaluate to `3`:

```
f(2)
//=> 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am habitual of writing imperative Java code and new to functional programming and hence finding it little difficult to digest the explanation that you provided. 
I am breaking down the function into parts :- 

def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)

=> According to my understanding here, when we apply union function like union(Set(1,2),Set(2)) then internally 'e' is the pointer that points to every element in the set. Please let me know if there is any concept of functional programming that I need to study first to understand this. 
Thanks.

Comment: No, `e` is not a pointer. It is the parameter of the function. Functions can have parameters. A parameter is kind of like a "hole" in a function definition, that we can fill in with a different value (called an "argument") every time we apply the function. It's *exactly* the same as a method. In the method `def inc(i: Int) = i + 1`, there is a parameter `i`, and when we call the method like `inc(2)`, we bind the value `2` as an argument to the parameter `i`, and the result is `3`.

Comment: In the function `val inc: Int ⇒ Int = i ⇒ i + 1`, there is a parameter `i`, and when we apply the function to an argument like `inc(2)`, we bind the value `2` as an argument to the parameter `i`, and the result is `3`.

Comment: Yeah, but we have not written 'e' anywhere in the function definition of union or intersect definition. So how does it get bounded to the function ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. First off, `union` and `intersect` are methods, not functions, so they don't *have* "function definitions". And secondly, why would `e` be declared as a parameter of `union` or `intersect`? It is a parameter of the function that is *returned* by `union` or `intersect`. Lastly, `e` is declared right there in the parameter list of the function that is returned by `intersect` or `union`, e.g. here: `(e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)` in this function literal `e` is declared to be the only parameter and declared to be of type `Int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Got it.

Answer (score 8):

```
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
```

Let's break this down into small chunks.

- `def union()` I'm defining a method that I'll call `union`.
- `(s: Set, t: Set)` This method will take 2 parameters that I'll call `s` and `t`, both of type `Set`.
- `: Set` This method will return a value of type`Set`. Hold on...what's a `Set`?
- `type Set = Int => Boolean` Ah, OK, `Set` is a function that takes an `Int` as a parameter and returns a `Boolean` as a result. Got it. Back to the `union()` method.
- `(e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)` This is a function that takes a single parameter of type `Int`. I'm going to call that parameter `e`. When this function receives an `Int` it will be fed to both `s` and `t`. `s` and `t` are both type `Set`, which means that when fed an `Int` they return a `Boolean`. So then we'll have 2 `Boolean` values and they'll be OR'd together to produce a single `Boolean`, which matches the definition of a `Set` (`Int` in, `Boolean` out), so we're done.

---

So now let's create an example and see how this is put to use.

```
val setA:Set = x => x == 5   //this Set is true only for 5
val setB:Set = y => y == 2   //this Set is true only for 2
val setU = union(setA, setB) //setA is parameter s, setB is parameter t

setU(2)  //'e' is now 2, this returns true
setU(5)  //'e' is now 5, this returns true
setU(25) //'e' is now 25, this returns false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am habitual of writing imperative Java code and new to functional programming and hence finding it little difficult to digest the explanation that you provided. 
I am breaking down the function into parts :- 

def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)

=> According to my understanding here, when we apply union function like union(Set(1,2),Set(2)) then internally 'e' is the pointer that points to every element in the set. Please let me know if there is any concept of functional programming that I need to study first to understand this. 
Thanks.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar; you are confusing the collection `Set`, from the Scala Standard Library, with the function `Set` defined for this exercise. `Set(1,2)` is a collection and doesn't fit the `union()` parameter type. See the usage example I've added to my answer. And, no, `e` is not a pointer. It is the parameter of a function. If I write `setU(7)` then `7` is passed to the function created by the `union()` method. `e` is assigned to the value `7` until the function returns.

Comment: Here's a description of something that might help you conceptually. Imagine a function that takes 2 parameters. Now invoke this function with only the 1st but not the 2nd parameter. Imperative languages won't allow this. It won't compile. But functional languages have something called "currying" which does allow this. When you invoke this function with only the 1st parameter what is returned is a new function that takes the 2nd parameter. When the new function is invoked with the proper parameter, the computation of the original function is completed.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the video lecture... we are supposed to assign an anonymous function to the base function.

here, (x: Int) is not brought from somewhere, consider it as a function parameter of a different function.
ex:

```
def num(s: FunSet): FunSet = (x: Int) => x

this is similar to, 
def function(x: Int) = x

def num(s: FunSet): FunSet = function
```

I Hope this helps future learners...! I had this doubt too...

Answer (score 1):

Remember how a `Set` was defined in this assignment: it's merely a function that takes an `Int` and returns a `Boolean`. When you pass some `Int` to this function, the function returns true if the `Int` is in the `Set`, and false if it is not. In other words, this type of `Set` isn't really a collection so much as a definition of what it means for something to be in a given `Set`.

Now, what does calling `union` between two `Set`s do? Well it produces a `Set` whose members are in at least one of those two `Set`s. Remember, a `Set` is just a `Int => Boolean` function, so:

`(e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)`

is a function which takes some `Int` parameter, call it `e`, and returns true if EITHER `s(e)` is true OR `t(e)` is true. According to the `union` method declaration, what are `s` and `t`?

`def union(s: Set, t: Set):`

`s` is the FUNCTION describing whether an `Int` is in the `Set` `s` or not; likewise for `t`. Thus, `s(e) || t(e)` means that `e` must be in one or both `Set`s, for the `union` of the two `Set`s to return true- which is exactly what the definition fo a `union` is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am habitual of writing imperative Java code and new to functional programming and hence finding it little difficult to digest the explanation that you provided. 
I am breaking down the function into parts :- 

def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)

=> According to my understanding here, when we apply union function like union(Set(1,2),Set(2)) then internally 'e' is the pointer that points to every element in the set. Please let me know if there is any concept of functional programming that I need to study first to understand this. 
Thanks.